# Best Way to Create a Class That Returns Commands on Regex Matches

Tags: c#, regex, oop, design-patterns

I have a bot that responds to user input, but before selecting what to do, it needs to run the string through Regex and select the appropriate command based on whether a match is successful. For example,

```
if (Regex.Match(...,.....).Success)
{
// Do #1
}
else if (Regex.Match(...,.....).Success)
{
// Do #2
}
```

This is not scalable or maintainable anywhere above 5 potential regex matches. What's a way to design a class that can step in to solve this for me?

Maybe a class called `CommandDictionary` that scans the strings for a match, generates a list of commands that corresponds to each successful regex match, and then picks the command that is associated with the highest priority? For example, if "Hello" matches "Greet" and "Ignore", but "Greet" has higher priority, the response will be Do Greet.

Comment: I would use a Publisher-Subscriber pattern for extensibility. Subscribers first register the Regex (or commands) they handle and a Callback. Publisher is the code that will process user input and loop through registered regexes and find relevant callbacks to fire.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can implement a strategy pattern. Create an interface, create concrete implementations of this interface, one for every command and then swap them out based on commands.

```
public interface IBotCommand
{
    string RegexMatch { get; }
    int Priority { get; }
    bool CanProcess(string input);
    void Do();
}


public class BotCommandOne : IBotCommand
{
    public string RegexMatch => "[a-z]g"; // whatever regex criteria you need for bot one
    public int Priority => 1;
    public bool CanProcess(string input)
    {
        return Regex.Match(input, RegexMatch).Success;
    }

    public void Do()
    {
       //Do command here for bot one
    }
}
```

Then if you're using dependency injection, go register all your interface/implementations as singletons.

Then in your calling code, you can inject an `IEnumerable<IBotCommand>`

```
public class BotClass
{
    private readonly IEnumerable<IBotCommand> _commands;

    public BotClass(IEnumerable<IBotCommand> commands)
    {
        _commands = commands;
    }

    public void PerformCommand(string userInput)
    {
         //go find the right command for your input
         var botCommand = _commands.Where(c => c.CanProcess(userInput).OrderBy(c => c.Priority).First();
         botCommand.Do();
    }

}
```

This way when you need to add more bot commands, you can just implement the interface, register it for DI and your calling code will just work.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you for your response, very helpful.